# Why does Apache return a 400 "bad request" error when connecting to it with "openssl s_client" even though it sends TLS SNI

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a website, accessible with HTTP over TLS. It is multi-homed, so there are several A DNS entries for the hostname. Additionally, there are several websites, with several hostnames, on the same set of IP addresses, so this is all setup with a few NameVirtualHost in Apache 2.

Accessing the website with a browser, or a WebDAV client, etc works like a charm.

But when I try to connect with "openssl s_client", I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Apache throws a 400 "Bad Request" error at me. Apache selects the correct X.509 certificate, so the SNI must have been set correctly by openssl. This happens as soon as I press "enter" on the "GET" line, even before I can add any header. The HTTP syntax I use (basically "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: hostname" works on the non-TLS version of the website (which only redirects to the TLS version), so that should not be the problem. The same HTTP syntax also works to connect to e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) over TLS (port 443), so again it looks correct.

Logs of the Apache server show a request with a trailing newline, maybe that's a hint. The log entry goes to the one for the *default* VirtualHost for that IP/port although Apache sent the X.509 certificate for the hostname I connect to, which is different from the default.

I have checked with wireshark that SNI is set in the ClientHello.

Here's an example session:

INPUT
`$ openssl s_client  -connect hostname:443`

OUTPUT

```
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = hostname
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = hostname
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(...)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = hostname

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3121 bytes and written 388 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: FBFD6172E3C659D4071B68A36BD5983A8571906C00190A745B5DAA1359D4087C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 21957A3C267DAA25CE2D7F6BFD3C3593CCFA1E6FC45C4DC5D0CE35C29175F7E9BBDD59EE6C213DC53B8291B7BD055238
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 18 4b 25 ae 49 61 e8 f3-73 b5 bb 3b 50 2f 1d c4   .K%.Ia..s..;P/..
    0010 - 7e 02 e9 41 01 9e ed 8b-a1 b6 ec 48 4d 12 11 f2   ~..A.......HM...

    Start Time: 1602857943
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 627DF7810556DB2918484F393E66DEA7BF22DD3A42288B47E46FCDCDEF176125
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 851978077C93284CB3D69B541B77844A48D1CFC8800F60B6F7CF3D297911D0D93E0E935017B78777E2BD51A29E13329F
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c0 1a 60 23 36 80 bf 27-83 0e 1f 26 4b 04 f2 53   ..`#6..'...&K..S
    0010 - a0 8a 2d 6e 41 44 17 c7-9b 11 5d dc 7f 08 71 fc   ..-nAD....]...q.

    Start Time: 1602857943
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
```

INPUT (note no blank line after the first one)
`GET / HTTP/1.1`

OUTPUT

```
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 14:19:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Content-Length: 322
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at default_hostname Port 443</address>
</body></html>
closed
```

**Note**: the error message mentions default_hostname, not hostname!

The corresponding Apache log entry is:
`default_hostname:443 1.2.3.4 - - [16/Oct/2020:16:19:11 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 3279 "-" "-"`

Note that default_hostname IS NOT hostname and that Apache sent the correct server certificate, so it has identified the correct VirtualHost! If I connect without SNI (openssl s_client -connect 4.3.2.1:443) then it sends the server certificate for default_hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...  "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 3279 "-" "-"

The line ending in a HTTP request should be `\r\n` and not `\n`. Try the `-crlf` option of `s_client` to translate an Enter into `\r\n` instead of only `\n`.

Also the server might have some limit in which time the request should be fully sent and it might not be fast enough to just type everything. Try cut+paste a pre-created request from a text file instead.

Comment: Yes, the -crlf option did it. Thanks. (Speed of typing was not the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You did actually send a malformed request. HTTP/1.1 requires the presence of the Host: header, and further with SNI, the content of the Host: header must match the SNI hostname.

Try again and this time provide the correct Host: header.

Comment: I cannot add any header. The error comes before I can put any header, as soon as I press "enter" after "HTTP/1.1". AFAIK, there must be a newline between the HTTP request and its headers. I don't mean an empty line! a newline to terminate the request line. The error appears as soon as I add that terminating newline. I apologise if I wasn't clear enough about that in my question, I thought I had explained it.

Comment: @LionelElieMamane That is rather strange. I can't reproduce it here. I don't get a response until I press enter twice. Check your keyboard, your terminal emulator, and maybe your openssl version?

Comment: The extra-double strange thing is that I can connect to e.g. www.google.com over TLS just alright with exactly the same setup (same openssl on the same machine with same keyboard and same terminal emulator). I type "GET / HTTP/1.1" then enter, then "Host: www.google.com" then enter *twice*, works right. Connecting to my Apache 2 on two different machines (different websites), I get the error as soon as I press enter after "GET / HTTP/1.1".